# Is there a way to lock a record or table using an OLEDB connection?

Tags: vb.net, oledb, vb6-migration

I am converting a legacy V6 app to VB.NET.
The app uses multiple Access 2000 mdbs for its datastore.

For the most part, this is a conversion job rather than a rewrite except in those places where VB.NET is just fundamentally different.
There are a number of challenging design decisions made by the original coder as they were learning VB6 throughout the process of building the app.

The original app used recordsets in VB6 to directly access the databases. I did not know of a way to do this in VB.NET so I am using oledb connection.
One of the core requests is to keep databases unchanged so that they can be read by both systems. Up to now that has been possible, but I have encountered the following issue:

The app (as one of its functions) tracks invoices and payments. The invoice number and Payment number are generated and assigned at the time an order is saved.

This was accomplished by having a status table that has one record in it. Among the pieces of data stored there are the last invoice number and the last payment number. When an order is stored,
the app puts the table in edit mode to lock it from reads and writes.

```
DataTables.dbStatus.Recordset.Edit
x = DataTables.dbStatus.Recordset.EditMode
```

It then reads the db to get the last invoice number and payment number and uses those as it then went through and saved all the pieces of data and wrote the new invoice and payment records. As it did so, it 'manually' incremented the numbers. When it was done it wrote the new last numbers used to the record and did a

DataTables.dbStatus.Recordset.Update

to finalize the update and unlock the table (or a cancelupdate if there was an error during the save, cleanup was performed during a subsequent save attempt.)

If someone else tried to save while another save was in progress, the app caught the locked db error and retried the save up to 5 times before it gave a try again error.

The reason for this is that they could have two people trying to enter an order at the same time. While the solution does not scale, the company is and always has been small, the max number of users that might be trying to save an order is three and is typically only two.

I don't know of a way to replicate this using oledb connection DB access.

I looked at transactions but that appears to be only at the connection (keeping threads from interfering with each other) not the db.

Before I go down to many more rabbit holes of dead ends, I am asking if there are any suggestions as to how I am might accomplish this or something similar. I am leaning more and more towards the "we will have to change the database" solution which leads to a number of ripple effect changes throughout the code.

ETA at the request of user9938

There are nine mdbs, each containing a number of tables pertaining the area of mdb represents.
There are no mdbs with a single table.
The mdb in question is the invoice.mdb.
It has about 50 tables with an additional 1w linked table (to excel spreadsheets and other mdbs)
The table in question is the DBstaus table it contains a single record with the following fields:

```
File Year Type: Short text
Archive Year Type: Number LongInt
catalog year Type: Short text
sales changed Type: Date/Time
Last ID Type: Number double
Invoice number Type: Number double
PO number Type: number longint
Payment number Type: number longint
Save Transaction Type: boolean
Last Inventory Date Type: Date/Time
Next Deposit Type: Date/Time
Next Past Due Type: Date/Time
Next Electronic Type: Date/Time
Next Conference Check Type: Date/Time
SS Type: Number long int
Company name Type: Short text
Address1 Type: Short text
Address2 Type: Short text
Phone Type: Short text
EMail Type: Short text
Tax ID Type: Short text
```

The Invoice Number and the Payment Number are the two field that are currently updated when the table when the lock is applied.
They contain the last invoice number used and the last payment number used.

Comment: In ADO.NET, you generally use [optimistic concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/optimistic-concurrency), i.e. don't lock anything and then try to save and only react if a concurrency violation occurs. Unless you specifically need pessimistic concurrency, I suggest that look into optimistic concurrency and handling concurrency violations instead. This would apply to any database and not just Access.

Comment: Please provide more info on the database structure. You mentioned that there are more than one database file, so also include that info as well.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are looking for on the DB structure here. Basically the addition MDBs aren't an issue here. Just one table in the invoice mdb that has one record that stores a number of items used by the app. 

In particular the two fields that are an issue are last invoice number and last payment number.

Those are the ones that the DB/Table/Record would need to be locked during save.

Comment: Information that can be used for testing that can be used to replicate your environment such as data types for fields and relationships for the tables. At a minimum the name of the table, the field (column) name that is used for invoice number and the data type of the field. The same for payment. Does each table have it's own .mdb file?

Comment: Edited to add the requested info.

Answer (score 0):

The information provided in the OP is rather limited. Since you plan to continue to use legacy apps that depend on information in `DBStatus`, as you stated, it's necessary to keep this information up-to-date, and also to prevent updates while you're performing your operations. Without knowing more about your tables and table relationships, using a transaction may work  - if any of the commands within the transaction fail, then any changes will be rolled back (undone). There may be alternative ways of achieving your goal, but that would require more information about your tables (and database relationships).

Give the following a try to see if it meets your needs:

**Note**: You'll have to add the code that updates the other tables when an order is created.

```
Public Function CreateOrder() As Integer
    'ToDo: add desired code

    Dim invoiceNumber As Double = 0
    Dim paymentNumber As Double = 0
    Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

    Try
        'create new instance
        Using cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
            'open
            cn.Open()

            'create transaction
            Using trx As OleDbTransaction = cn.BeginTransaction()
                Try
                    Try
                        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Invoice Number], [Payment Number] from DBStatus;", cn, trx)
                            Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                                If reader.HasRows Then
                                    While reader.Read()
                                        'read by position in SQL statement
                                        'If reader(0) IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader(0)) Then
                                        'invoiceNumber = CDbl(reader(0))
                                        'End If

                                        'If reader(1) IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader(1)) Then
                                        'paymentNumber = CDbl(reader(1))
                                        'End If

                                        'read by column name
                                        If reader("Invoice Number") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader("Invoice Number")) Then
                                            invoiceNumber = CDbl(reader("Invoice Number"))
                                        End If

                                        If reader("Payment Number") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader("Payment Number")) Then
                                            paymentNumber = CDbl(reader(1))
                                        End If
                                    End While
                                End If
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    Catch ex As OleDbException
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException 1) - " & ex.Message)
                        Throw ex 're-throw exception
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder 1) - " & ex.Message)
                        Throw ex 're-throw exception
                    End Try

                    'increment values
                    invoiceNumber += 1
                    paymentNumber += 1

                    'update DBStatus - Invoice Number and Payment Number
                    Try
                        Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE DBStatus set [Invoice Number] = ?, [Payment Number] = ?", cn, trx)
                            'OLEDB doesn't use named parameters in SQL. Any names specified will be discarded and replaced with '?'
                            'However, specifying names in the parameter 'Add' statement can be useful for debugging
                            'Since OLEDB uses anonymous names, the order which the parameters are added is important
                            'if a column is referenced more than once in the SQL, then it must be added as a parameter more than once
                            'parameters must be added in the order that they are specified in the SQL
                            'if a value is null, the value must be assigned as: DBNull.Value

                            With cmd.Parameters
                                .Add("@invoiceNumber", OleDbType.Double).Value = invoiceNumber
                                .Add("@paymentNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = paymentNumber
                            End With

                            'Debug.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText)

                            'ToDo: remove the following code that is for debugging
                            'For Each p As OleDbParameter In cmd.Parameters
                            'Debug.WriteLine(p.ParameterName & ": " & p.Value.ToString())
                            'Next

                            'execute
                            rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End Using
                    Catch ex As OleDbException
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException 2) - " & ex.Message)
                        Throw ex 're-throw exception
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder 2) - " & ex.Message)
                        Throw ex 're-throw exception
                    End Try

                    Try
                        'ToDo: add code to insert order information

                        Dim sqlText As String = String.Empty

                        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlText) Then
                            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, cn, trx)

                            End Using
                        End If
                    Catch ex As OleDbException
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException 3) - " & ex.Message)
                        Throw ex 're-throw exception
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder 3) - " & ex.Message)
                        Throw ex 're-throw exception
                    End Try

                    'successful
                    'commit transaction, if not commited, any changes (inserts/updates) will be undone
                    trx.Commit()

                Catch ex As OleDbException
                    'rollback transaction
                    trx.Rollback()

                    Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException trx) - " & ex.Message & "; Transaction rolled back.")
                    Throw ex
                Catch ex As Exception
                    'rollback transaction
                    trx.Rollback()

                    Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder trx) - " & ex.Message & "; Transaction rolled back.")
                    Throw ex
                End Try
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message)
        Throw ex
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder) - " & ex.Message)
        Throw ex
    End Try

    Return invoiceNumber
End Function
```

**Usage**:

```
Dim invoiceNumber As Integer = CreateOrder()
```

Here's some additional code that may be useful:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class HelperAccess2000

    Private _accessFilename As String = String.Empty
    Private _connectionStr As String = String.Empty

    Public Property AccessFilename
        Get
            Return _accessFilename
        End Get
        Set(value)
            _accessFilename = value

            'initialize
            Initialize(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Sub New(accessFilename As String)
        'initialize
        Initialize(accessFilename)
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateOrder() As Integer
        'ToDo: add desired code

        Dim invoiceNumber As Double = 0
        Dim paymentNumber As Double = 0
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

        Try
            'create new instance
            Using cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
                'open
                cn.Open()

                Using trx As OleDbTransaction = cn.BeginTransaction()
                    Try
                        Try
                            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [Invoice Number], [Payment Number] from DBStatus;", cn, trx)
                                Using reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                                    If reader.HasRows Then
                                        While reader.Read()
                                            'read by position in SQL statement
                                            'If reader(0) IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader(0)) Then
                                            'invoiceNumber = CDbl(reader(0))
                                            'End If

                                            'If reader(1) IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader(1)) Then
                                            'paymentNumber = CDbl(reader(1))
                                            'End If

                                            'read by column name
                                            If reader("Invoice Number") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader("Invoice Number")) Then
                                                invoiceNumber = CDbl(reader("Invoice Number"))
                                            End If

                                            If reader("Payment Number") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not IsDBNull(reader("Payment Number")) Then
                                                paymentNumber = CDbl(reader(1))
                                            End If
                                        End While
                                    End If
                                End Using
                            End Using
                        Catch ex As OleDbException
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException 1) - " & ex.Message)
                            Throw ex 're-throw exception
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder 1) - " & ex.Message)
                            Throw ex 're-throw exception
                        End Try

                        'increment values
                        invoiceNumber += 1
                        paymentNumber += 1

                        'update DBStatus - Invoice Number and Payment Number
                        Try
                            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE DBStatus set [Invoice Number] = ?, [Payment Number] = ?", cn, trx)
                                'OLEDB doesn't use named parameters in SQL. Any names specified will be discarded and replaced with '?'
                                'However, specifying names in the parameter 'Add' statement can be useful for debugging
                                'Since OLEDB uses anonymous names, the order which the parameters are added is important
                                'if a column is referenced more than once in the SQL, then it must be added as a parameter more than once
                                'parameters must be added in the order that they are specified in the SQL
                                'if a value is null, the value must be assigned as: DBNull.Value

                                With cmd.Parameters
                                    .Add("@invoiceNumber", OleDbType.Double).Value = invoiceNumber
                                    .Add("@paymentNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = paymentNumber
                                End With

                                'Debug.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText)

                                'ToDo: remove the following code that is for debugging
                                'For Each p As OleDbParameter In cmd.Parameters
                                'Debug.WriteLine(p.ParameterName & ": " & p.Value.ToString())
                                'Next

                                'execute
                                rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                            End Using
                        Catch ex As OleDbException
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException 2) - " & ex.Message)
                            Throw ex 're-throw exception
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder 2) - " & ex.Message)
                            Throw ex 're-throw exception
                        End Try

                        Try
                            'ToDo: add code to insert order information

                            Dim sqlText As String = String.Empty

                            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sqlText) Then
                                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, cn, trx)

                                End Using
                            End If
                        Catch ex As OleDbException
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException 3) - " & ex.Message)
                            Throw ex 're-throw exception
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder 3) - " & ex.Message)
                            Throw ex 're-throw exception
                        End Try

                        'successful
                        'commit transaction, if not commited, any changes (inserts/updates) will be undone
                        trx.Commit()

                    Catch ex As OleDbException
                        'rollback transaction
                        trx.Rollback()

                        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException trx) - " & ex.Message & "; Transaction rolled back.")
                        Throw ex
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        'rollback transaction
                        trx.Rollback()

                        Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder trx) - " & ex.Message & "; Transaction rolled back.")
                        Throw ex
                    End Try
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (CreateOrder) - " & ex.Message)
            Throw ex
        End Try

        Return invoiceNumber
    End Function

    Public Sub Initialize(accessFilename As String)
        'set value
        '_connectionStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};", accessFilename) 'deprecated
        _connectionStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};", accessFilename)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText As String)

        Using cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
            'open
            cn.Open()

            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, cn)
                'execute
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Function TblDBStatusExecuteNonQuery(sqlText As String, invoiceNumber As Double, paymentNumber As Integer) As Integer

        'when specifying value for a string, to pass a null or empty value, specify: "" or Nothing

        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

        'create new instance
        Using cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
            'open
            cn.Open()

            'create new instance
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, cn)

                'OLEDB doesn't use named parameters in SQL. Any names specified will be discarded and replaced with '?'
                'However, specifying names in the parameter 'Add' statement can be useful for debugging
                'Since OLEDB uses anonymous names, the order which the parameters are added is important
                'if a column is referenced more than once in the SQL, then it must be added as a parameter more than once
                'parameters must be added in the order that they are specified in the SQL
                'if a value is null, the value must be assigned as: DBNull.Value

                With cmd.Parameters
                    .Add("@invoiceNumber", OleDbType.Double).Value = invoiceNumber
                    .Add("@paymentNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = paymentNumber
                End With

                'ToDo: remove the following code that is for debugging
                'For Each p As OleDbParameter In cmd.Parameters
                'Debug.WriteLine(p.ParameterName & ": " & p.Value.ToString())
                'Next

                'execute
                rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return rowsAffected
    End Function

    Private Function TblDBStatusExecuteNonQuery(sqlText As String, fileYear As String, archiveYear As Integer, catalogYear As String, salesChanged As DateTime, lastId As Double, invoiceNumber As Double, poNumber As Integer, paymentNumber As Integer, saveTransaction As Boolean, lastInventory As DateTime, nextDeposit As DateTime, nextPastDue As DateTime, nextElectronic As DateTime, nextConference As DateTime, ss As Integer, companyName As String, address1 As String, address2 As String, phone As String, email As String, taxId As String) As Integer
        'use for INSERT / UPDATE 

        'when specifying value for a string, to pass a null or empty value, specify: "" or Nothing

        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

        'create new instance
        Using cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
            'open
            cn.Open()

            'create new instance
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, cn)

                'OLEDB doesn't use named parameters in SQL. Any names specified will be discarded and replaced with '?'
                'However, specifying names in the parameter 'Add' statement can be useful for debugging
                'Since OLEDB uses anonymous names, the order which the parameters are added is important
                'if a column is referenced more than once in the SQL, then it must be added as a parameter more than once
                'parameters must be added in the order that they are specified in the SQL
                'if a value is null, the value must be assigned as: DBNull.Value

                With cmd.Parameters
                    .Add("@fileYear", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileYear), DBNull.Value, fileYear)
                    .Add("@archiveYear", OleDbType.Integer).Value = archiveYear
                    .Add("@catalogYear", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(catalogYear), DBNull.Value, catalogYear)
                    .Add("@salesChanged", OleDbType.Date).Value = salesChanged
                    .Add("@lastId", OleDbType.Double).Value = lastId
                    .Add("@invoiceNumber", OleDbType.Double).Value = invoiceNumber
                    .Add("@poNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = poNumber
                    .Add("@paymentNumber", OleDbType.Integer).Value = paymentNumber
                    .Add("@saveTransaction", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = saveTransaction
                    .Add("@lastInventory", OleDbType.Date).Value = lastInventory
                    .Add("@nextDeposit", OleDbType.Date).Value = nextDeposit
                    .Add("@nextPastDue", OleDbType.Date).Value = nextPastDue
                    .Add("@nextElectronic", OleDbType.Date).Value = nextElectronic
                    .Add("@nextConference", OleDbType.Date).Value = nextConference
                    .Add("@ss", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ss
                    .Add("@companyName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(companyName), DBNull.Value, companyName)
                    .Add("@address1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(address1), DBNull.Value, address1)
                    .Add("@address2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(address2), DBNull.Value, address2)
                    .Add("@phone", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(phone), DBNull.Value, phone)
                    .Add("@email", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(email), DBNull.Value, email)
                    .Add("@taxId", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(taxId), DBNull.Value, taxId)
                End With

                'ToDo: remove the following code that is for debugging
                'For Each p As OleDbParameter In cmd.Parameters
                'Debug.WriteLine(p.ParameterName & ": " & p.Value.ToString())
                'Next

                'execute
                rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return rowsAffected
    End Function

    Public Function TblDBStatusInsert(invoiceNumber As Double, paymentNumber As Integer) As Integer
        'insert Invoice Number and Payment Number into DBStatus

        Dim sqlText As String = "INSERT INTO DBStatus([Invoice Number], [Payment Number]) VALUES (?,?);"

        Try
            'insert
            Return TblDBStatusExecuteNonQuery(sqlText, invoiceNumber, paymentNumber)
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblDBStatusInsert - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblDBStatusInsert) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function TblDbStatusGetInvoiceNumberAndPaymentNumber() As DataTable
        'get Invoice Number and Payment Number from DBStatus

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
        Dim sqlText As String = "SELECT [Invoice Number], [Payment Number] from DBStatus;"

        Try
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
                'open
                con.Open()

                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, con)
                    Using da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        'fill DataTable from database
                        da.Fill(dt)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

            Return dt
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblDbStatusGetInvoiceNumberAndPaymentNumber - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblDbStatusGetInvoiceNumberAndPaymentNumber) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function TblDBStatusUpdate(invoiceNumber As Double, paymentNumber As Integer) As Integer
        'update Invoice Number and Payment Number in DBStatus

        Dim sqlText As String = "UPDATE DBStatus set [Invoice Number] = ?, [Payment Number] = ?;"

        Try
            'update
            Return TblDBStatusExecuteNonQuery(sqlText, invoiceNumber, paymentNumber)
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblDBStatusUpdate - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblDBStatusUpdate) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function TblDBStatusUpdate(fileYear As String, archiveYear As Integer, catalogYear As String, salesChanged As DateTime, lastId As Double, invoiceNumber As Double, poNumber As Integer, paymentNumber As Integer, saveTransaction As Boolean, lastInventory As DateTime, nextDeposit As DateTime, nextPastDue As DateTime, nextElectronic As DateTime, nextConference As DateTime, ss As Integer, companyName As String, address1 As String, address2 As String, phone As String, email As String, taxId As String) As Integer
        'update Invoice Number and Payment Number in DBStatus

        Dim sqlText As String = "UPDATE DBStatus set [File Year] = ?, [Archive Year] = ?, [Catalog Year] = ?, [Sales Changed] = ?, [Last ID] = ?, [Invoice Number] = ?, [PO Number] = ?, [Payment Number] = ?, [Save Transaction] = ?, [Last Inventory] = ?, [Next Deposit] = ?, [Next Past Due] = ?, [Next Electronic] = ?, [Next Conference] = ?, SS = ?, [Company Name] = ?, Address1 = ?, Address2 = ?, Phone = ?, EMail = ?, [Tax ID] = ?;"

        Try
            'update
            Return TblDBStatusExecuteNonQuery(sqlText, fileYear, archiveYear, catalogYear, salesChanged, lastId, invoiceNumber, poNumber, paymentNumber, saveTransaction, lastInventory, nextDeposit, nextPastDue, nextElectronic, nextConference, ss, companyName, address1, address2, phone, email, taxId)
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblDBStatusUpdate - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblDBStatusUpdate) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

**Usage**:

```
Private _accessFilename As String = "C:\Temp\TestAccess2000.mdb"
Private _helper As HelperAccess2000 = Nothing
              
Private Sub InitializeHelper()
    If _helper Is Nothing Then
        'create new instance
        _helper = New HelperAccess2000(_accessFilename)
    End If
End Sub
               ...

InitializeHelper()

Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

rowsAffected = _helper.TblDBStatusInsert("1", "3")
rowsAffected = _helper.TblDBStatusUpdate("2", "4")

Dim invoiceNumber As Integer = _helper.CreateOrder()
Dim dt As DataTable = _helper.TblDbStatusGetInvoiceNumberAndPaymentNumber()
```

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look at it and see if works for what I am doing.

Comment: Question: It is my understanding that transactions are only relevant to threads on the machine where the code is being run. Meaning, that it is unclear to me how this prevents two users is entering orders and both trying to update with the same invoice and payment numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the character limitation for a post, I wasn't able to add these to the other post. The following may be useful:

- [Introduction to lock files (laccdb and ldb) in Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/lock-files-introduction)
- [Row-level locking in Access 2000](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?8679-Row-level-locking-in-Access-2000)
- [ADO.NET Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-architecture?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [System.Data.OleDb Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8)
- [OleDbConnection.BeginTransaction Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.begintransaction?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_OleDb_OleDbConnection_BeginTransaction)
- [IsolationLevel Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.isolationlevel?view=netframework-4.8)
- [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Microsoft Jet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-microsoft-jet)
- [The difference between ODBC, OLE DB, and ADO](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/the-difference-between-odbc-ole-font-colorreddbfont-and-ado_8_8_30033173.html)
- [Connect to data in an Access database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/connect-to-data-in-an-access-database-windows-forms?view=vs-2019)
- [Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa140011(v=office.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com)
- [ADO.NET Best Practices](https://www.codemag.com/article/0311051/ADO.NET-Best-Practices)
- [Migrating from ADO to ADO.NET](https://catalogimages.wiley.com/images/db/pdf/9780764576782.excerpt.pdf)
- [VB Helper](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_db_transaction.html)
- [DataTypeEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum?view=sql-server-2016)
- [Microsoft Office Access Database Engine 2007 crashes on a multithreaded application](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a0433fc0-81ea-425d-9356-5e72ba6a176c/microsoft-office-access-database-engine-2007-crashes-on-a-multithreaded-application?forum=accessdev)
- [CREATE TABLE statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql)
- [Using ADO with Microsoft Visual Basic and Visual Basic for Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic?view=sql-server-ver15)
- [Locking Recordsets in Microsoft Access 2000](https://www.developer.com/guides/locking-recordsets-in-microsoft-access-2000/)
- [Connection object (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/connection-object-ado)