# How to implement transaction in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, transactions, ado.net

Is it possible to execute a commit or rollback of a transaction A when executing successfully a transaction B? If transaction B is not successful, when transaction B is not successful, I want to do is rollback everything, I try the following way but the commit of transaction A doesn't is done

```vb
Public Sub Guardar(ByVal operacion As String, ByVal clvSesion As Integer, ByVal importeEfectivo As Decimal, ByVal importeCambio As Decimal,
                   ByVal Contrato As Int64, ByVal Cajera As String, ByVal Sucursal As Int32, ByVal Caja As Int32,
                   ByVal Tipo As String)

    Try
        Dim sqlTranPayment As SqlTransaction
        Dim sqlTranInvoice As SqlTransaction

        If operacion = "Payment" Then
            Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MiConexion)
                cnn.Open()
                sqlTranPayment = cnn.BeginTransaction()

                Try
                    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GrabaPago", cnn)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Transaction = sqlTranPayment

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gloClv_Session", clvSesion)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Efectivo", importeEfectivo)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cambio", importeCambio)

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    'sqlTranPayment.Commit()

                    cnn.Close()
                    cnn.Dispose()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    sqlTranPayment.Rollback()
                End Try

            End Using
        ElseIf operacion = "Invoice" Then
            Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MiConexion)
                cnn.Open()
                sqlTranInvoice = cnn.BeginTransaction()

                Try
                    Dim Clv_FacturaSalida1 As Int64
                    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GrabaFactura", cnn)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Transaction = sqlTranInvoice

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contrato", Contrato)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clv_Session", clvSesion)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cajera", Cajera)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sucursal", Sucursal)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caja", Caja)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", Tipo)

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    sqlTranInvoice.Commit()
                    sqlTranPayment.Commit()
                    GloClv_Factura = cmd.Parameters("@Clv_FacturaSalida").Value

                    cnn.Close()
                    cnn.Dispose()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    sqlTranInvoice.Rollback()
                    sqlTranPayment.Rollback()
                End Try

            End Using
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You can pass the transaction object in case you want everything in same transaction

Comment: You only create one or another in your code. In any case you only need one, as you only have one connection.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68518236/is-there-a-way-to-lock-a-record-or-table-using-an-oledb-connection/68552637#68552637 - just replace everything for SQL server (ex: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, etc...)

Comment: You need to familiarise yourself with the DRY principle, i.e. Don't Repeat Yourself. You should extract the common code and write once, which includes the connection and the transaction. You're trying to fix a problem that doesn't exist because you never create two transactions.