# Transactions With C#, MS Access, Visual Studio DataSet Designer

Tags: c#, ms-access, transactions

I am using C# with an MS Access database. I am also using the Visual Studio DataSet Designer. I have several inserts into the database to make. I have never used transactions. Is it possible to use a transaction? If so, could you please provide an example. If this can not be done please let me know so I do not keep looking for solutions. Thank you.

I have tried the following 2 ways :

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    transaction.Commit();
}

using (var transaction =  cn.BeginTransaction())
{
    ts.Complete();
}
```

On the TransactionScope I received the following error on my insert command:
SystemInvalidOperationException: The ITransactionalLocal Interface is not supported by the Microsoft ACE.OleDb.12.0.0 provider. Local transactions are unavailable with the current provider.

On the other transaction I do not see how to provide a connection object. My connection is in the dataset Designer code used as a library.

Comment: MS Access isn't a RDBMS (relational database management system) and doesn't have real transactions. However, the following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68552637/10024425

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did go through the article. The example the article shows uses the second option above. The problem I have is I do not know what to do with the connection because I am using the dataset designer file as a library. I can not find a way to reference the connection object.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using? Also, what version of .NET Framework? According to [Walkthrough: Create a Dataset with the Dataset Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/walkthrough-creating-a-dataset-with-the-dataset-designer?view=vs-2022): _Datasets and related classes are legacy .NET technologies from the early 2000s..._

Comment: The following may also be of interest: [TRANSACTION statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/transaction-statement-microsoft-access-sql)

Comment: I am using VS 2022 and .Net Framework 4.8. The version of Access that I am using is Access 365 MSO (version 2304 Build 16.0.16327.20200) 64 bit. I have the dataset designed and refer to it through a .dll file in my project. My project itself has no connection. I access it through table adapters. The table adapters do not seem to have an accessible connection. TransactionScope seems to be the only thing that might work, but so far nothing has worked. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution and [Considerations for unattended automation of Office in Microsoft 365...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/considerations-unattended-automation-office-microsoft-365-for-unattended-rpa)